# Session is not storing variables - Django

Tags: django, authentication, session, django-rest-framework

I've been having trouble storing my tokens on session.
I've found few solutions on stackoverflow but none of them worked.

currently, I store user's token when client send a POST request to */api/login*

and here is my views logic

```
request.session['token'] = auth.token.key
request.session.modified = True
```

- I'm 100% sure `auth.token.key` is not `None` and the logic stores just fine.

but when it comes to */api/update* (some sample api),
I always get `None`

here is how I get the Item from session:

```
print(request.session.get('token'))
```

** The Code above always returns None**

I read the Django docs. I set both the session middleware and session app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'user'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'user.auth.AuthBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

I've done all the migrations.`django_session` table exists.

**EDITED:**

login view:

- I have custome authentication backend

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):

    # convert json data into dictionary
    data = get_data(request)

    print(request.session.get('token'))

    auth = authenticate(
        email = data['email'],
        password = data['password']
    )

    if auth:
        # store user's token into sesion
        request.session['token'] = auth.token.key
        print(request.session['token'])

        user = UserModelSerializer(auth.user)

        return Response(
            user.data,
            status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        )

    else:

        return Response(
            message("user doestn't exist | incorrect password"),
            status = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )
```

Update View (where I can't get the session data):

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def update(request):
    print(request.session.get('token'))
    return Response("its ok.")
```

Comment: can you show us the function when you saved session

Comment: sure, I updated the question